# Creating Object of Objects from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, parameters

Example of get params from URL:

`const getParams = {status: 'SUCCESS', productType: 'DATA'}`

This is how I would like to shape my data from the get params object:

```
{
  {
    productType: {label: 'Data', value: 'DATA'},
  },
  {
    status: {label: 'Success', value: 'SUCCESS'},
  }
}
```

I tried using `Object.entries(getParams)` with `.map()`, but this obviously returns a list of objects which is not what I want.

Any help would be great, I think I've been looking at it for too long to see a clear solution.

If any further info is required, please let me know, but this is basically it

Comment: And what do you want to do with `dateRange`, just ignore it ?

Comment: Sorry @A.RAZIK `dateRange ` shouldn't be in the `getParams` example

Comment: Your desired object isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment I don't want to create a JSON object.

Comment: @KD1 What you have above looks like you are attempting to get JSON. If you desire something else, you have to state what it is to get help...a string?

Comment: Yeah, as @peinearydevelopment said, the output is not a valid object !

Comment: This is JSON: `{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car": "honda"}` - the key and value is wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

How about when you define the objects this way:

```
{
    productType: {label: 'Data', value: 'DATA'},
    status: {label: 'Success', value: 'SUCCESS'}
}
```

This way you can access the objects through the properties. Remember JavaScript objects are all about property and value hence if you are to have objects inside other objects they will have to be contained in properties that you can access.

Comment: This wont work as I get the data from the get params in the URL. So it can differ each time. The above is an exmple of one instance

Answer (score 0):

you can use map and object.entires to achieve your desired output,this approach is a little bit verbose However, you can optimise it

```js
const getParams = [{status: 'SUCCESS', productType: 'DATA'}]

map=new Map()
getParams.map(o=>{
  map.set("productType",{label:o.productType,value:o.productType}),
  map.set("status",{label:o.status,value:o.status})})
output={}
  obv= Object.fromEntries(map)
  Object.entries(obv).forEach((o,i)=>{
        output[i]={[o[0]]:o[1]}
  })

  console.log(output)
```